# How to hibernate AWS EC2 instance from inside it?

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, hibernate

I have an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03) which I can [hibernate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hibernating-instances.html) from outside it — using the console, or AWS CLI.

Is there any way to hibernate it by running a command inside it? Some Linux distros support `systemctl hibernate` but this one doesn't even have `systemctl`.

For those who tend to answer along the lines "you don't need this, do that instead" I confirm that I know what I am doing and I do need hibernation, not stop/snapshot/restore etc.

Update:

Calling AWS CLI from inside the VM is not desirable because it calls an API *external* to the VM (which then apparently calls something back inside the VM) — credentials/IAM roles need to be maintained etc. What is it that EC2 calls inside the VM to get it suspend all processes, save RAM to disk and shutdown?

Comment: Virtual machines are not very different to bare metal solutions, just the disk driver and ACPI drivers might be a little different.  If you don't want to use the AWS tools provided then look for generic solutions on how to make linux hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Amazon Linux AMI anyways because it comes with all the AWS tools preinstalled. So, use the standard clients to tell the AWS controller to make a snapshot of the VM for later restoring, and turn it off. That's in the end what hibernation does.

Note: hibernation is not really a great idea for a VM on AWS in many cases. Many instance types will still be billed in shut down mode. Make a snapshot/image, save it, and delete the VM to avoid that problem. Generally, a common strategy for cloud VMs is that your VMs are actually throwaway items, and there'd be no situation where you'd want to hibernate them. You store the data you need to resume service on some volume, which will be used by any freshly booted copy of your VM, right away. That way, you actually get reliability.

Comment: "make a snapshot of the VM for later restoring" — do you mean disk/volume snapshot? If so then sorry, this does not answer the question at all. I do have a valid use-case for **hibernation** (as opposed to shutdown/delete/restore).

Comment: @Greendrake but hibernation is literally just storing the RAM contents to disk, turning off, and restoring on boot. That's what it does!

Comment: I know! And that is _exactly_ what I need. Do I necessarily need to tell why?

Comment: @Greendrake with "snapshot" I mean this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-ec2-now-lets-you-pause-and-resume-your-workloads/

Comment: @Greendrake you don't have to tell me why, all I'm saying is that AWS offers this functionality. It's not called hibernation, because it's not your VM's kernel storing the RAM to its storage, but AWS storing the full VM state, but it's the same thing. You're acting as if hibernation was different than storing RAM to storage and restoring it later. That's exactly what AWS does for you, *without* support from the VM's operating system. (They need that anyways. Otherwise, they could not migrate instances between machines seamlessly. Hyperscalers are built around that ability.)

Comment: You appear to be misunderstanding how EC2 hibernation works. It doesn't store the full VM state. It saves RAM to the disk inside the VM. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-hibernate-overview.html): "The hibernation freezes all of the processes, **saves the contents of the RAM to the EBS root volume**, and then performs a regular shutdown."

Comment: @Greendrake ah! so, that's exactly what you want, no?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want RAM on the disk, and restore the state as quickly as possible when needed.

Comment: So, as said in my answers' first sentence: `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids ${myinstanceid}` from within the instance?

Comment: Haha, I did consider that, but that will call the EC2 API _outside_ the instance which will call something back _in_ it to save RAM to the disk. Shouldn't there be a direct way?

Comment: I think AWS loves their REST APIs so much, this *might* be the directest way… not sure though, but I don't think there's an easier way. What I dislike is the dissemination of management secrets into a VM, indeed.

Comment: I strongly doubt AWS have done anything at the kernel level to implement hibernation.  Linux has hibernation built in and the most likely implementation of this for AWS is that they've put some userland control around it.  IE the most "direct" route to make AWS EC2 Linux hibernate wil be the same as how to make *any* linux box hibernate.  Admittedly that's notorious for being a bit of a minefield so a ready boxed userland tool is helpful.

Comment: @PhilipCouling good point, and IIRC that thing is FOSS, so you might be able to read it.